# NuxtJS and Auth Route Exemptions

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm current using Nuxt.js and the authentication module it comes with.

Is it possible to create exemptions in auth to prevent automatic redirection to the login page when a user is not logged in?

Take the following as an example:

1. User is not logged in and navigates to: http://localhost:3000/#/password-reset
2. They will be redirected to the login screen: http://localhost:3000/#/login

I want to create an exemption so that all routes are protected by auth, which they already are, with the exception of the page to reset passwords (http://localhost:3000/#/password-reset).

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your are using [nuxt-auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/).

Create a middleware `middleware/isAuth.js`:

```
export default function({ app, error }) {
  if (!app.$auth.loggedIn) {
    // If you want to redirect to login page
    app.router.push('/password-reset')

    // If you want to throw error, use this:
    return error({
      statusCode: 403,
      message: 'You are not allowed to see this'
    })
  }
}
```

In page you want to protect, declare your middleware:

```
export default {
    ...
    middleware: ['isAuth'],
    ...
}
```

It will prevent page if user is not logged in.
To log user, you should use [`loginWith`](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth.html#loginwith-strategyname-args).